# Speech Recognition - Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition

I am working on an app with the function of speech recognition or command, I want to know if its possible to recognize speech with the following conditions.

1. Recognise without using SpeechRecognizerUI
2. Recognise as an app running in background
3. Recognise for as much time as I want or in intervals

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Speech Recognition API from the WP8.

Just check this [sample](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/04/01/windows-phone-8-speech-recognition-into-your-apps.aspx)

and the [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207021%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) from msdn

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes I have been through this article, it doesnt fulfil the conditions I've mentioned. But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you are Searching for Voice commands for Windows Phone.

Users can use voice commands to launch your app and to execute an action.

You can add voice command functionality to your app by completing these three steps:

1. Create a Voice Command Definition (VCD) file. This is an XML document that defines all the spoken commands that users can say to initiate actions when launching your app.
2. Add code to initialize the VCD file with the phone's speech feature.
3. Add code to handle navigation and to execute commands.

for more Refrence you can follow this [Voice commands for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206959(v=vs.105).aspx) and [Voice Commands on Windows Phone](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-8-Voice-Commands.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am already familiar with the procedure you have shared yet it doesnt not fulfil my requirements I have mentioned in 3 points above.